# Org mode 20161102 Latex export: Images without {center} environment

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, images

Present 20161102 org mode now exports images by default wrapped in `\begin{center}..\end{center}` environments.

This destroys layouts and confuses export scripts made with earlier versions or different settings in mind.

(`\centering` is added in the case of figures. This is in principle a bit less obtrusive, as here we are telling org to prepare the environment.)

How can I turn off this "feature"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize the variable `org-latex-images-centered`.